Вечная загрузка при авторизации VS Code
Столкнулся с следующей проблемой: при попытке авторизоваться в VS Code (через Microsoft или GitHub аккаунт) вылезает обычное уведомление об авторизации, но в браузере ничего не открывается (На компе использую яндекс браузер, крайне редко Google Chrome).
Что я пробовал:

Очистить кэш и куки в браузере
Отключить брандмауэр
Отключить все фоновые программы, которые хоть как-то связаны с сетью
Переустанавливать VS Code

ОС: Windows 10 22H2
VS Code: 1.83.1
